# Insert dateTimePicker value to excel date cell using OLE DB in C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, datetimepicker

I'm writing my first program, a database one, and I'm stuck on inserting a new row of info into my excel database file. The problem is each row of data has a date cell in the A column. I want to be able to choose a date in the dateTimePicker, input the rest of my data (name, job number ...etc )via text boxes and then on a button click insert all that data into a new row. I can do it using Interop but I don't like it because it opens up excel and takes too long. My code at the moment works nicely for all the text box inputs but won't work for the date. The Date column in my excel file is in "Date" format.

So my question is this, Can I use OLE DB to insert a dateTimePicker value into a date formatted excel cell?

Here's my code, really appreciate the help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label60.Text == "new")
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                string sql = null;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Declan\\Documents\\Declan\\output.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\" ");
                MyConnection.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

                DateTime date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;


                string post1 = textBox3.Text;
                string type1 = textBox4.Text;
                string source1 = textBox5.Text;
                string income1 = textBox6.Text;
                string prof1 = textBox7.Text;
                string jobnum1 = textBox8.Text;

                sql = "Insert into [Database$] (date,postcode,type,source,income,profession,customerid) values('" + date1 + "','" + post1 + "','" + type1 + "','" + source1 + "','" + income1 + "','" + prof1 + "','" + jobnum1 + "')";
                myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            label60.Text = "edit";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I've changed the code to use oledb parameters. No idea how this has fixed it but looks like the excel date column needed to take a string with the format dd/MM/yyyy

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label60.Text == "new")
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Declan\\Documents\\Declan\\output.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\" ");
                MyConnection.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

                DateTime date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                string date2 = date1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");


                myCommand.CommandText = "Insert into [Database$] ([date],postcode,type,source,income,profession,phonenumber) values(@date, @post, @type,@source,@income,@prof,@jobnum)";
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",date2);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post", textBox3.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", textBox4.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", textBox5.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@income", textBox6.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prof", textBox7.Text);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobnum", textBox8.Text);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MyConnection.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

         label60.Text = "edit";
        }
    }
```